# Installing nginx with docker

Tags: docker, nginx

Having followed a tutorial on installing nginx with docker I thought everything would work ok. The tutorial is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I_9-xWmkh28

I am getting a 404 when I try to look at the port where nginx lives: localhost:8000

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS with docker version 24.0.7, build afdd53b. with docker-compose version 1.25.0

Below are the three config files I have set up following the tutorial: nginx,dockerfile and docker-compose

```
server {
  listen 80;
  index index.php
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_page 404 /index.php;
  root /var/www/public/;
  location ~\.php$ {
    try_files $uri= 404;
    fastcgi_pass app:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    gzip_static on;
  }
```

---

```
FROM  php:8.0.2-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
git \
curl \
zip \
unzip


WORKDIR /var/www
```

---

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    container_name: programgwithio-app
    restart: always
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ../src:/var/www

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19-alpine
    container_name: programgwithio-nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ../src:/var/www
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
```

---

nginx log

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is not a file or does not exist
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2023/12/15 12:34:02 [error] 22#22: *1 open() "/var/www/public404" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.27.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8000"
2023/12/15 12:34:02 [error] 22#22: *1 open() "/var/www/public404" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.27.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8000"
172.27.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2023:12:34:02 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
172.27.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2023:12:34:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023/12/15 12:34:03 [error] 22#22: *1 open() "/var/www/public404" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.27.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8000"
2023/12/15 12:34:03 [error] 22#22: *1 open() "/var/www/public404" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.27.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8000"
```

If anyone requires other information please get back. : - )

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `try_files $uri= 404;` by `try_files $uri =404;`

Comment: It worked like a dream. Thanks.  Could you explain the difference flymerry. : - )